# requesting excel formula to compare columns but going in order and skipping blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare

Trying to setup a formula in excel to compare 2 colums, sample data set below.
Considering there will be blanks in column B and we must go in order

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | match |
| 4 | 3 | difference |
| 5 | blank | skipped |
| 6 | 5 | match |
| 6 | 5 | difference |
| 8 | 6 | match |
| blank | blank | skipped |
| blank | 8 | match |

Tried a few formulas but not giving the results required

```
=IF(B1="", "", IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1, IF(B:B<>"", B:B), 0)), "Match", "Difference"))
```

---

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"", B1<>"", A1=B1), "Match", IF(B1="", "", "Difference"))
```

---

```
=IF(A1<>"", IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B1), IFERROR(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(B:B), 0)), ""), IF(A1=B1, "Match", "Difference")), ""), "")
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using both version 2013 and 2016

Comment: I think you would need helper columns pre- Excel 365

Comment: Isnt column C the helper column in this case, thats where the formulas are tried.

Comment: Why is the first 6-5 `match` while the 2nd one is `difference`? Why is blank-8 `match` but 5-blank `skipped`? Why is 8-6 `match`? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: I _think_ OP is looking at the nth number in column B (e.g. the first occurrence of 5 in col B is the third number in that column) and comparing it against the nth number in col A (which in this case would also be 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested if with COUNTIF

```
=IF(B1="","skipped",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)>=COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1),"match","difference"))
```

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya seeing patterns has always been easy for me.  I use it in my work all the time.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much. Pattern or not, basically we can do this manually by removing the blanks in excel, then comparing the cells, so both the cells are side by side. In this case wanted the formula to do all the work as the cells are not side by side because of the blanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different take on this

```
=IF(B1="","skipped",IF(B1=INDEX(A:A,COUNT(B$1:B1)),"match","difference"))
```

but I realise this will break after the blanks in column A and something more would be required like an mmult.

[image]

---

This was my thinking if the pattern continues like this, to use Mmult to find the next value in column A to compare:

```
=IF(B1="","skipped",IF(B1=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(COUNT(B$1:B1),
MMULT(IF(COLUMN($A$1:$J$1)<=ROW($A$1:$A$10),1,0),SIGN(A$1:A$10)),0)),
"match","difference"))
```

[image]

---

In a further test, my result (column E) would be at variance with @Scott Craner's (Column F) because I am comparing 8 against 7 and 9 against 8:

[image]

---

I you were able to set up a helper column starting from (say) C1 which counted the number of cells in column A containing a number up to the corresponding row, then you could use a much simpler formula which would work better with larger amounts of data:

```
=IF(B1="","skipped",IF(B1=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(COUNT(B$1:B1),
C$1:C$10,0)),"match","difference"))
```

Comment: Just doing a copy & paste of OP's data - yes I should have made them into blanks!